# Sharepoint Calendar Missing Normal Look

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

Good Day Everyone,

I am having issues with creating a Sharepoint Calendar.  It is missing a lot of displays like the quick launch on the left hand side and well at the display box on the top left that shows days and months.  It almost seems like it is in safe mode.  When I create calendar on different sites, this does not happen.  Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: could you attach a screen shot?

Comment: I apologize, it's on a separate private network...  Basically the display just shows the calendar.  It doesnt have the top left box where you can toggle months and no quick links on the left side.  It seems like its in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check or try.

- The site template under (Settings > Change the look) can be set to Seattle or Oslo that will determine if the site has a left navigation or not. Do you know if your company is using a custom template / master page that could be causing some sort of issue?
- try creating a new calendar view on the list to see if there is something wrong with the other view.

also what version of SharePoint are you on?